# throwing exceptions of objects on the stack, mem leak with new?

Tags: c++, exception

Is it a bug to do this:

```
if(some_error)
  throw Cat("Minoo");
```

Where Cat is a class.

Then in some other function that called the method that threw the exception...

I would have:

```
catch(const Cat &c)
{ 
}
```

If it is invalid, do I use new Cat("Minoo");

Would that cause a memory leak?

Comment: Actually, throwing cats is more than a bug - it's downright mean. :)

Comment: @Steve: No worry, doesn't cats have 7 lives ..LOL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1)  Invalid? No, that's precisely what you're supposed to do: throw an object. The object in the throw-statement may be on the stack, but it is copied when it is thrown. Compare, for example, the effect of executing return Cat("Minoo");

2)  Will throwing a pointer cause the pointed-to object to be leaked?  Yes, if the object was allocated on the heap and unless you arrange to delete it. But you should avoid throwing pointers as a general rule.

Answer (score 6):

What you have now is what everyone should be doing, and most do. Throw the object itself and catch by const-reference.

Throwing pointers has hairy issues such as "who deletes it?".

More information [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html).

Answer (score 5):

What you wrote is perfectly valid, and is generally preferable to allocating exceptions objects on the heap.

If you were to use new, you would of course get a memory leak unless you deleted the object in an exception handler that caught the exception.

[This question in the C++ faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.6) (and the two questions afterwords) address this.